# How to configure keymap of Rubymine for rails console

Tags: ruby, rubymine

To configure keymap of Rubymine, I mine I opened `[Preference]->[Keymap]`, but I couldn't find how to configure keymap only for rails console.

By default in rails console `ctrl + r` reload rails environment by `reload!` command. Can I set `reverse-i-search` for `ctrl + r` like bash shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to keymap and browse history (under other) its set to option command E (on mac) you can change it there.

Comment: I'm using mac, and tried to use `reverse-i-search` by  `Command + E`, but it doesn't worked. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which v of rubymine are you using?

If you go to preferences under appearance behavior select keymap, click the other drop down and scroll down to browse history check what the shortcut is there.

Comment: That was `control+option+E` and conflicted other key mapping. After reconfiguration I could use the command history. It was bit different what I wanted though, I think this is the most similar function in RubyMine. Thanks!